# Redis failed to start while running a program with Python Ray Library - RuntimeError: Couldn't start Redis

Tags: python, redis, ray

I am trying to use ray[tune] on a linux server where I am just a user without the root permission.

After installing ray[tune] and running python code `from ray import tune` , I got an error message:

```
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

Followed the instructions online, I changed the environment variables:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/USERNAME/dependency/glibc-2.17/lib/:/lib64/:/usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/lib64/`
`/home/USERNAME/dependency/glibc-2.17/lib/ld-2.17.so /home/USERNAME/python3.8.6/bin/python`

Then I was able to run the python code `from ray import tune`.

But when I ran the below code in [link](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/tune/)

```
from ray import tune


def objective(step, alpha, beta):
    return (0.1 + alpha * step / 100)**(-1) + beta * 0.1


def training_function(config):
    # Hyperparameters
    alpha, beta = config["alpha"], config["beta"]
    for step in range(10):
        # Iterative training function - can be any arbitrary training procedure.
        intermediate_score = objective(step, alpha, beta)
        # Feed the score back back to Tune.
        tune.report(mean_loss=intermediate_score)


analysis = tune.run(
    training_function,
    config={
        "alpha": tune.grid_search([0.001, 0.01, 0.1]),
        "beta": tune.choice([1, 2, 3])
    })

print("Best config: ", analysis.get_best_config(
    metric="mean_loss", mode="min"))

# Get a dataframe for analyzing trial results.
df = analysis.results_df
```

I got error: `RuntimeError: Couldn't start Redis`

logs/redis.err says:

thirdparty/redis/src/redis-server: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument

*Ray version is 1.0.0, Python version is 3.8.6

Any fix/reason for this failure?

Comment: Which linux distribution & version are you using?

Comment: CentOS release 6.8, Linux 4.1.15.pnotify x86_64

Comment: Let's continue here https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/11395